# Affine transformations that correspond to entire complex functions

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, linear-transformations, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

I assume the following is a standard consideration and question, but I don't know how to prove it:

There is a trivial one-to-one correspondence between affine transformations $f = (f_x,f_y)$ of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
f_x \\ 
f_y \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b  \\ 
c & d  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
e \\ 
f \\ 
\end{bmatrix} $$

with $ad - bc \neq 0$ and complex functions $g(u + iv) = g_u(u,v) + ig_v(u,v)$ with

$$\begin{bmatrix}
g_u \\ 
g_v \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b  \\ 
c & d  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ 
v \\ 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
e \\ 
f \\ 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Some such functions are entire functions, e.g. the identity function

$$\begin{bmatrix}
g_u \\ 
g_v \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  \\ 
0 & 1  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ 
v \\ 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

others are not, e.g. the complex conjugate

$$\begin{bmatrix}
g_u \\ 
g_v \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  \\ 
0 & -1  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ 
v \\ 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

which corresponds to reflection at the real axis.

I guess that the only affine transformations that correspond to entire complex functions are compositions of [(uniform) scalings, rotations, and translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Image_transformation). Especially reflections don't qualify. Of non-uniform scalings and shearings (= non-uniform translations) I doubt it.

The qualifiying transformations would simply correspond to functions

$$g(z) = z_1\cdot z + z_0$$

with $z_0 = e + if$ and

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a & b  \\ 
c & d  \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = r\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\varphi) & \sin(\varphi)  \\ 
-\sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi)  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

for $z_1 = re^{i\varphi}$.

My questions are:

> 1. Is this correct?
> 2. How to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. I suppose that you know how to prove that functions of the type $z\mapsto z_1\times z+z_0$ are entire. Now, suppose that $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb R$ and that you consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}F\colon&\mathbb C&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&x+yi&\mapsto&ax+by+e+(cx+dy+f)i.\end{array}$$Is it entire? It is clear that it is entire if and only if the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb C&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\x+yi&\mapsto&ax+by+(cx+dy)i\end{array}$$is entire. But if it is entire, then it is holomorphic and the Cauchy-Riemann equations tell you then that $a=d$ and that $c=-b$. So, take $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_0=e+fi$. Then, $F(z)=z_1\times z+z_0$.